# Installing PHPexcel in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: software-installation, php

How to install PHPexcell in my ubuntu 14.04?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following two commands:

```
sudo pear channel-discover pear.pearplex.net 
sudo pear install pearplex/PHPExcel
```

Comment: @dai  It throws the following error:
Discovering channel pear.pearplex.net over http:// failed with message: channel-add: Cannot open "http://pear.pearplex.net/channel.xml" (Connection to `pear.pearplex.net:80' failed: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known)
Trying to discover channel pear.pearplex.net over https:// instead
Discovery of channel "pear.pearplex.net" failed (channel-add: Cannot open "https://pear.pearplex.net/channel.xml" (Connection to `pear.pearplex.net:443' failed: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known))

Answer (score 0):

I finally got it by using GIT.

Install git first:

```
sudo apt-get install git
```

- Go get the download URL from git at [here](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel).
- Click on the green "Clone or Download" button.
- Copy the URL.

I've included the current URL in the code below, but unsure if it can change so always good to just double check.

Go back to your command line and make sure you are in the folder you want to download PHPExcel to.

Then use:

```
sudo git clone https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel.git .
```

The dot at the end is important as it tells the system to download it to the directory your are in.

It should then be a matter of using include in your code to be able to use it.